# How to Remove Default Row In Wpf data Grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am using a WPF Data Grid. Whenever it is loaded there is a blank default row. How can I disable the default row from appearing like you can in the Windows Forms grid.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is the row for new entries. If you don't want let the user create new entries or if you handle this from code, e.g. with a add-button, disable the `CanUserAddRows`-option.

```
<DataGrid  CanUserAddRows="False" />
```

Comment: ITS working BUt Bcoz OF this i m loss my datagrid Selection Change Event

Comment: @Chunmun Tyagi: Between the selection of elements? I have a lot of DataGrids in my apps (WPFToolkit and .net4) and I never have observed a problem with the SelectionChanged-event. But I'm not 100percent sure if I use it often because I mostly bind from a ViewModel to the SelectedItem. What happens exactly? Does it not fire if you change the selected row? Maybe it's meaningfull to open a new question for this. Is it with .net 4 or the toolkit-version?

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I also want to hide that blank row.  I'm using VSE 2012, and a datagrid with an ObservableCollection, and unchecking the option for CanUserAddRows does nothing for me.

Comment: work perfectly for me, the row doesn't appear anymore !

Comment: @NerfHerder it works if you place that code in xaml, that checkbox doesn't seem to work for me either